# Adding element to XML using linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

i have this piece of code which i use to add some elements:

```
  string xmlTarget = string.Format(@"<target name='{0}' type='{1}' layout='${{2}}'  />",
                                                new object[] { target.Name, target.Type, target.Layout });
            Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var xmlDoc = XElement.Load(configuration.FilePath);
            var nlog = xmlDoc.Elements("nlog");

            if (nlog.Count() == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            xmlDoc.Elements("nlog").First().Elements("targets").First().Add(xmlTarget);
            xmlDoc.Save(configuration.FilePath,SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
            configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("nlog");
            return true;
```

it supposed to add a target to the xml , problem is it replace "<" with "`&lt;`" and ">" with "`&gt;`" which mess up my xml file.

how do i fix this ?

**Note** please dont pay attention to nlog, i`m concerned about the linqtoxml problem.

Comment: Quick note: there's an easy way to get us to not pay attention to particular parts of the code... trim them out of the post. (As an aside, using `if (!nlog.Any())` is better than using `if (nlog.Count() == 0)`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently adding a *string*. That will be added as content. If you want to add an *element*, you should parse it as such first:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xmlTarget);
```

Or preferrably, construct it instead:

```
XElement element = new XElement("target",
    new XAttribute("type", target.Name),
    new XAttribute("type", target.Type),
    // It's not clear what your format string was trying to achieve here
    new XAttribute("layout", target.Layout));
```

Basically, if you find yourself using string manipulation to create XML and then parse it, you're doing it wrong. Use the API itself to construct XML-based objects.